# Attach a specific menu to a specific page

Tags: wordpress, menu

In my Wordpress website:

I have two pages, one is in Deutsch and one is in English. 
I have two menus, same deal.

I would like to display the english menu when browsing the page in English and display the deutsch menu when browsing the page in Deutsch.

I cannot use any multilingual pluging unfortunately.
Is there any way to achieve this with a basic wordpress installation?

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Comment: Hey Daniel, so far I tried using WPML which worked kinda nice but for some reason we had to end up uninstalling. I looked into the admin console some way to attach a menu to a specific page but I can't find anything. I also tried this idea but to no avail (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77220/how-to-change-menu-according-to-the-language)

Comment: I'd suggest a multi-language plugin, Owen's answer below beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a multi-language plugin?

Assuming you're right about the idea of not being able to use such a plugin, two solutions come to mind:

- Use custom fields and conditional logic to display one menu or another
- Use page templates to display different menus

You can override the layout of a page by creating a file called page-{slug}.php or page-{id}.php, in which {slug} and {id} should be substituted for the slug or id of the page you wish to make a template for.  In this page template you could copy the original layout, but alter the wp_nav_menu command to select a different menu.

There are a few other ways to do it, but those two seem like sensible options to me.

Comment: I guess I could simply call wp_nav_menu in the header.php don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Put this code in header.php while calling navigation menu:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>

<div id='frontPageBanner'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header-1', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</div>

<?php } elseif (is_archive()) { ?>

<div id='archiveBanner'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header-2', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</div>

<?php } elseif ( is_page($pageID)) { ?>

<div id='pageIdBanner'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header-1', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Thanks.